# Run a script from inside a shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have been trying to run a shell script from inside a shell script. The name of the file is 'hello.sh'

The 'hello.sh' file first enters into one path and then executes other commands.
The command runs a python file.

But, the first line is showing that there is no directory.

> : No such file or directory cd: /home/<user>/sample/hello/

hello.sh

```
cd ~/sample/hello
python helloworld.py
```

I have given permission to the shell script.

> chmod +x ./hello.sh

Also, when I run the command - 'cd ~/sample/hello' from ouside, that is directly from the shell, it is going inside the directory /sample/hello. From there I am able to run the command - 'python helloworld.py'

So, the commands are running from shell direclty, but when I put it in a script and try to run the script, it shows that the directory does not exist.

The directory is present and the python file is also present inside that directory. What can be the issue?

Comment: Is your homedir `/` (running as root) ?

Comment: No this user is not the root. Just a user

Comment: Do you have `\r` or other special characters in your file?

Comment: Which file? Python? No, there are no special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Just added '&&' between the two commands and put them in one line. So, hello.sh looks like -

```
cd ~/sample/hello && python helloworld.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your script is trying to open `/sample/hello` instead of `/home/<user>/sample/hello`

Try with the absolute path.

Comment: Once it is executed, it is taking the absolute path - /home/<user>/sample/hello. Still, it shows that error.

Comment: And what's the output of `/home/<user>/sample/hello` ?

Comment: : No such file or directory cd: /home/<user>/sample/hello

Comment: Then the directory doesn't exist

Comment: It exists. When I run the same command in shell directly, it goes inside the directory

Comment: Please update the question with the commands you are executing in shell and their outputs and also with how are you executing the script and its exact output.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197273/discussion-between-zumo-de-vidrio-and-teekay).